# Using Handlebars templates with external JSON

Tags: handlebars.js

I feel really stupid, but I can't figure this out. I'm trying out Handlebars.js, but I can't get it to display data from the Twitter API. Here's what I've got:

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/alexlande.json',
  dataType : 'jsonp',
  success : function( tweets ) {

    var source = $('#tweet-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = tweets;

    $('#container').html(template(context));
  }
});
```

That doesn't display anything in my template, but the following code works as expected:

```
var source = $('#tweet-template').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = { tweets : [
  { text : "This is a test tweet" },
  { text : "And this is yet another" },
  { text : "And you always need three test tweets, right?" }
]};

$('#container').html(template(context));
```

This is something simple that I'm not understanding, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are passing an Object to the template function.

```
var context = { tweets : [
  { text : "This is a test tweet" },
  { text : "And this is yet another" },
  { text : "And you always need three test tweets, right?" }
]};

$('#container').html(template(context));
```

But in the code that doesn't work:

```
 success : function( tweets ) {

    var source = $('#tweet-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = tweets;

    $('#container').html(template(context));
  }
```

That **'tweets'** variable is not an Object, its an Array.

I think that is what you are doing wrong. Try this:

```
 success : function( tweets ) {

    var source = $('#tweet-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = tweets;

    $('#container').html(template({tweets:context}));//wrap in an Object.
  }
```

Posting your template could help more as well.

Comment: Wow, this saved my life when using MySQL returned data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert string into object, because Handlebar template wrap only object.

**Try this**

```
success : function( tweets ) {
var source = $('#tweet-template').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var context = $.parseJSON(tweets); // convert string into object.
$('#container').html(template(context)); //wrap in an Object.
```

}