# Can't display external JSON data in Backbone + Handlebars

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I'm using Thorax (Backbone + Handlebars) to develop an app, and am trying to load in an external JSON file that will be used in the template. Working with Coffeescript as well.

My test JSON data:

```
{
   "name" : "John Doe"
}
```

My template:

```
Thorax.templates['space'] = Handlebars.compile """
  <h2>Hello, {{name}}.</h2>
"""
```

The success function of my Ajax call:

```
success: (json) =>
    data = {space: json}
    $(app.appContainer).html(@template(data))
```

The entire process works up until actually displaying the data within the template. So all I get is **Hello,.** - I've tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462494/using-handlebars-templates-with-external-json) and assigned the JSON data to an object, with no luck. And before you ask, I've `console.log`'ed `json` to check that the JSON data is in fact coming through.. it is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to say `@template(json)` instead of wrapping the incoming `{name: 'John Doe'}` in another object?

Comment: That would make sense, I was just doing that because of the answer I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462494/using-handlebars-templates-with-external-json though I did try it the way you suggested with no luck either

Comment: `@template(json)` should work (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8ugBr/) unless someone is messing around behind your back.

Comment: Hmmm.. definitely couldn't get it to work like that. I fear someone's messing around. I'd be happy to post more of my code if it'll help? Really want to get this figured out :(

Comment: Are you sure `json` is an object? Just a shot in the dark, looks like it should work to me.

Comment: Upon console.log'ing `json` I get this in the console: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f988s89htaqnc4a/Screenshot%202014-04-24%2011.52.06.png - is that a proper JSON object?

Comment: That looks like a string to me. Compare `console.log({ name: 'John Doe' })` and `console.log("{\n\"name\" : \"John Doe\"\n}")` to be sure.

Comment: Aha! I get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6o66zwxos9rlol0/Screenshot%202014-04-24%2012.16.02.png) - Soooo this means my data is getting escaped, right? I just need it to return as an actual object, like you mentioned before.

Comment: Maybe check for a Content-Type problem, maybe the server is saying `text/plain` instead of `application/json`. You can always parse the JSON yourself if necessary but that would be a last resort.

Comment: You got it. I made the server set `application/json` as the Content-type. Thaaaaank you! Feel free to put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying `@template(json)` should work if `json` really is the `{ name: 'John Doe' }` object. But it looks like you're getting a JSON string in your `json` argument rather than a parsed object. That would explain the results you're seeing from `console.log`, the output in your console looks more like what

```
console.log("{\n\"name\" : \"John Doe\"\n}")
```

would produce than what

```
console.log({"name": "John Doe"})
```

would produce.

Perhaps your server is sending back JSON with the wrong Content-Type so no knows that it is supposed to go through [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before your success handler is called. Try fixing your server code to include a `Content-Type: application/json` header; then you can say:

```
success: (json) =>
    $(app.appContainer).html(@template(json))
```

and it should work. If you can't do that then, as a last resort, you could parse the JSON yourself:

```
success: (json) =>
    json = JSON.parse(json)
    $(app.appContainer).html(@template(json))
```